# Convert minutes and seconds to hours, minutes and seconds in Excel

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I have the value `123:04` in an Excel cell and it currently stands for 123 minutes and 4 seconds.How can I convert this value to hours minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If simply changing the format to `[hh]:mm:ss` does not change to the correct format, then it would need to be in `[hh]:mm` format or it is a string.  Use this:

```
=A1/60
```

Then format the result as `[hh]:mm:ss`

[image]

Comment: ... or if it is already formatted as `[mm]:ss`, change the formatting to `[hh]:mm:ss`.

Comment: Awesome. It was already a time format and the second formula worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeeped I honestly thought that `[mm]:ss` was not an optional format.  But I now see that assumption to be in error.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the [ and ] allow any of the time format masks to extend beyond their natural limit, e.g. [hh] for hours > 24, and [mm] or [ss] for minutes or seconds > 60 (subject to an upper limit of a signed short integer). Only one set of [ and ] can be used in a time format mask.

Comment: As long as I'm being a pain in the tuchus, the second method's maths operation will also work on text-that-looks-like-time making the first method redundant. Could have saved a bit of typing.

Comment: @Jeeped 8p YEAH YEAH YEAH. :)

Comment: "Then format the result as [hh]:mm:ss" - where is that icon on my Excel 365 ribbon?

Comment: @AndrewKoper new questions get new post, and that question is better suited for SuperUser.com.